# Corresponding Objects to Tables in Database Design

Tags: python, sql, database, database-design, sqlalchemy

Say I have an object which is composed of multiple pieces of information: `rating`, `like`, `comment`. Let's call this object a `preference`. Each `preference` would be associated with a `user`. That is, each `user` has many `preferences`, but each `preference` has only one `user`.

In what ways would it be better for my `preference` object to be structured into the design of the database, for example, as a table with columns `rating`, `like`, `comment`, and a foreign id key pointing to a `user`? A `user`'s `preference` may or may not contain a `rating`, `like`, or `comment`, and if they don't, the entry for that specific column would be left blank.

And in what ways would it be better for my `preference` object to be instead assembled outside of the design of the database, by collecting each piece it needs from several tables, a table each for `rating`, `like`, and `comment`, and each table having a column pointing to a foreign id key of a `user`? If the `user` lacks a `rating`, `like`, or `comment`, that table would simply not have an entry for that `user`.

Specifically I will be using python and sqlalchemy to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the Entity-Attribute-Value model:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx